# How to use BitMap in Android for following design?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have just started to use `Bitmap` and want to try design something this button:

[image]

I am using `SpannableString` for further process. How can I get this type of shape with rounded corner with `Bitmap`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Bitmap usage in activity**

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestImages extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test2.png");
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
}
```

**For rounded image, try the below code**

rounded_corner.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" >
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#1c1b20" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" >
    </padding>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Add this file to your drawable folder

**main_activity.xml**

Add this line to your textview in XML

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
```

Comment: I don't have ImageView as you can see in post that I am using `spannable` String only